# How to create a branch in subversion excluding certain files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

Usually I'm using Tortoise SVN to manage my projects and it would be especially great if somebody could give a list of steps how to achieve it using Tortoise SVN but any other solution is good enough.

I need to create a branch of a folder but I would like to exclude certain files or folders from the source. Is it possible? How to do it? Normally it is a matter of excluding, let's say *.sln files.

The solution to create a full branch and then remove extra files does not work in my case because there are security requirements to completely block access to the excluded files on the branch. With this approach there is a way to see removed files in the history.

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Simplest possible to my mind is just create branch, then remove unnecessary items and commit your changes to the branch.

Comment: Forgot to mention one thing. It's a little bit more complex and there is a security reason not to do it like that. With this approach everybody who has access to this branch can see the deleted files in the history but they should not.

Comment: Ok. Next obvious solution: take all needed items and place them to another folder manually. Then import that folder into the "branch" in SVN.

Comment: Fair idea but in this case a complete copy is created basically duplicating data. Creating an ordinary branch just copies references without duplicating data. Besides that, the history won't be maintained for newly imported files. They will be treated as newly added files.

Answer (score 1):

Branch in Subversion is just `svn cp` from one node to another. You can prepare your branch by `WC -> WC` copy (or `svn switch` to not-existing branch) and removing unwanted files before commit into branch: URL->URL is not single possible way of branching